# Ethereumjs testrpc getting 400 Bad Request when navigating to localhost:8545

Tags: testrpc, ethereumjs

I've followed the instructions for installing ethereumjs testrpc (https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc)

I have `Node v.6.9.1`

I'm on macOS so I have `XCode Command Line Tools` installed.

Running `npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc` completed without error.

Running `which testrpc` returns `/usr/local/bin/testrpc`

Then I run `testrpc` and no error occurs and it states `Listening on localhost:8545`

When I navigate to localhost:8545 I get `400 Bad Request`.

I haven't done anything yet and I'm not sure why this is happening. Has anyone else come up against this issue when installing ethereumjs testrpc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestRPC is a ethereum node client, which provides you with a sandbox blockchain, where there is no mining and virtually endless amounts of ether for developing and testing. You can use it for developing with [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle), for example. The address you have there is the so called RPC address, it tells things where to find an ethereum node client. Therefore, you cannot open it in a browser.

Comment: so, how i  can to get transaction info by locally hash which ganache shows ?